# All Subsequences Monotone Except The Sequence Itself

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Just had my Calculus 1 exam and wanted a clarification.

Say An is a sequence, the claim was:
If all of An's Subsequences are monotone except for An itself, An is monotone.

It didn't specifically state that An isn't monotone, so I couldn't find a counterexample.
If it's true, would like to know how to prove it.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: think of the most simple, obvious way to extract a subsequence

Comment: I guess it'd be the sequence itself? But it specifically stated it doesn't necessarily include it. Or maybe omitting the first number?

Comment: omitting the first is my idea (the simplest way to extract a *proper* subsequence)

Comment: If you want to prove it, you need to consider two subsequences.  For the second subsequence, remove any element other than the first or second from the original $A_n$.  (the resulting proof should make it apparent why we shouldn't just remove the second element)

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean that you know that all subsequences of $a_n$ are monotone except for the sequence itself, i.e., you can assume that all proper subsequences are monotone and need to show that $a_n$ is monotone.

Additionally, I guess the statement is that all subsequences share the same monotonicity. Otherwise, it's pretty clear that whole sequence cannot be monotone. For example, if $\{a_{n_k}\}_k$ is increasing and $\{a_{m_j}\}_j$ is decreasing, we have that $a_{n_2}\geq a_{n_1}$ and $a_{m_1}\leq a_{m_2}$. Now you need to split into cases, I'll discuss here just one, the others are similar. Assume $m_1\leq n_1 < n_2\leq m_2$. If $a_{m_1}\leq a_{n_1}$, you have $a_{m_2}\leq a_{m_1}\leq a_{n_1}\leq a_{n_2}$ so you can only have monotonicity if you have equality everywhere. It's easy to see the other cases if you just try to plot $2$ pairs of values from two subsequences of different monotonicity.

Therefore I will assume that what you want to prove is this. Let $a_n$ be a sequence such that for each strictly increasing sequence of naturals $\{n_k\}_k$ that is not the entire sequence of natural numbers, the subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}_k$ is (wlog) increasing. Show that $\{a_n\}_n$ is increasing.

Assume that $\{a_n\}_n$ is not increasing. Then there exist some indices $1\leq i <j$ such that $a_i>a_j$. Define the sequence of naturals $\{n_k\}_k$ by setting $n_1=i$ and $n_2=j$ and $n_k=j+10k$ for $k\geq 3$. Clearly this sequence is (strictly) increasing and it is not the full set of naturals (in particular, the average gap between consecutive terms is $10$). Therefore $\{a_{n_k}\}_k$ is a proper subsequence of $\{a_n\}_n$ and must be, by assumption, increasing, meaning that $a_i=a_{n_1}\leq a_{n_2}=a_j$, contradiction.

Comment: Thanks, that's ultra clear.

Comment: No problem. Sometimes, the formalism of proofs can be quite unintuitive and cumbersome, but it is the only way to make sure that your argument is fully correct. Always start by getting an intuitive idea and then trying to nail it down formally. That's how you can fact check yourself.